# What file does firefox use for the autocompletion as you enter a url?

Tags: firefox

I'm using windows 7 and was able to get to the folder where firefox stores your profile information by searching

`%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`

However I was unable to find the file(s) that store the information used to autocomplete the url as your're typing it.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses your history (places.sqlite), your bookmarks (places.sqlite), and your open tabs (uh... not in any file).